# Encode if-branch and recursion in eager evaluation

Tags: if-statement, factorial, evaluation, lambda-calculus

As far as I know, in eager evaluation we cannot encode the if-branch and recursion the same way as in normal-order evaluation.

For example, in lambda calculus if-branch and factorial(fac) can be encoded

```
if e1 e2 e3 = e1 e2 e3
fac = Y(λf.λn. if n=0 1 n*f(n-1))
Y = λf.(λx. f(xx))(λx. f(xx))
```

Can we encode the if-branch and recursion in eager evaluation?
If we can i like to know how should we encode if-branch and factorial in eager evaluation using lambda calculus.

```
if e1 e2 e3 = ???
fac = ???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap them both in a lambda that ignores its argument, then if can choose the branch by forcing it, passing in some dummy value.

So it can be done but only if 'if' is used like this: `if e1 (λ_.e2) (λ_.e3)`

Comment: Thank you for answer! :) It really helps.